# CreateThread string to LPVOID

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, process

I'm trying to make a thread to handle ZIP archiving:

```
 HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        ZipProcess,
        (LPVOID) cmdline.c_str(),
        0,
        NULL);
```

I'm passing the command line argument as a string in the `lpParameter`.

I keep getting this error:

> ...argument of type 'void (MyClass::)(std::string) {aka void
>   (MyClass::)(std::basic_string)}' does not match
>   'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE {aka long unsigned int (*)(void*)}'|

I've tried several things - passing by reference, [writing to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450439/cannot-pass-string-to-createthread-receiver), a `reinterpret_cast`, and others, but the error persists.  How to fix this?

Comment: It's talking about `ZipProcess` not matching the `DWORD (WINAPI *)(void *)` signature that is required.

Comment: Take also a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c

Comment: Also note that C++11 has the `<thread>` header as well.

Comment: @Fermat2357 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx (the _beginthreadex docs) says "This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime."  That sounds like a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong spot. The compiler is complaining about the third argument, the thread procedure. Your error looks GCCish, and that says something along the lines of *Error passing in argument 3...*

To fix it, you need a function signature that actually matches what the function takes (this is an expanded version of the `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` typedef), namely:

```
DWORD (WINAPI *lpStartAddress)(LPVOID)
```

The three problems with your definition are:

1. Your function does not use the WINAPI (A.K.A `__stdcall`) calling convention.
2. Your function has a `std::string` parameter instead of `LPVOID` (A.K.A. `void *`).
3. Your function is a class member. You need either a static member or a free function in order for it not to expect an additional `this` argument, causing a signature mismatch.

Comment: Note also that the lifetime of `c_str()` is too short to pass to `CreateThread`.